# How to transfer all storage from google cloud to local storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I would like to export all of the images, videos, and data that I have in my google storage to my local directory since I am canceling my subscription. But there is no proper documentation on doing that, I found how to transfer it from 1 service provider to another but not to export.

https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/how-to?authuser=4

That's the only documentation I found, but it doesn't mention how to transfer locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you install `gsutil`, you can use the [`cp`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp) command like this:

```
gsutil -m cp -r gs://YOUR_BUCKET_NAME/*.* .
```

Use `-m` to perform a parallel copy, in case of a large number of files. Use `-r` to copy also the contents of the subdirectories. Then, `*.*` is a regex for "any filename and file extension" and `.` at the end will download it at the directory where you are running `gsutil`. You can find help about these flags [in here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/TopLevelCommandLineOptions)

Repeat this for all the buckets you may have, and you are set.

Another alternative would be using either [the libraries or the API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#storage-download-object-python), but that would require more set up from you, while `gsutil` is 'easier' to do.

Comment: @wandos, you have the explanations of the flags that Mangu mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/TopLevelCommandLineOptions)

Comment: @Yurci Thanks for the link, mate :) I'm adding it to my answer.